# Didn't manage to call Azure IoT Edge module direct method

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am running an IoT edge Module and have registered method callbacks.

SetMethodHandlerAsync and SetMethodDefaultHandlerAsync

but neither is ever called...

Initiating direct message calls from Azure Portal

> Failed to invoke device method: {"message":"Device {\"Message\":\"{\\"errorCode\\":404103,\\"trackingId\\":\\"126e3eef616c409385e73128aef94b21-G:17-TimeStamp:08/23/2018 12:29:35\\",\\"message\\":\\"Timed out waiting for device to connect.\\",\\"info\\":{\\"timeout\\":\\"00:00:10\\"},\\"timestampUtc\\":\\"2018-08-23T12:29:35.2214374Z\\"}\",\"ExceptionMessage\":\"\"} not registered"}

From VsCode

> Failed to invoke Direct Method: Not found

Do I miss to set any required configuration?
Is there a naming convention or a path to be specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From VS code seem to invoke method to a device instead of a module because it doesn't require enter module id.

From Azure Portal, it works for me.

[image]

Register method and implement method call back:

```
    static async Task Init()
    {
        AmqpTransportSettings amqpSetting = new AmqpTransportSettings(TransportType.Amqp_Tcp_Only);
        ITransportSettings[] settings = { amqpSetting };

        // Open a connection to the Edge runtime
        ModuleClient ioTHubModuleClient = await ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(settings);
        await ioTHubModuleClient.OpenAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("IoT Hub module client initialized.");

        await ioTHubModuleClient.SetMethodHandlerAsync("Write", WriteConsole, null);
        Console.WriteLine("IoT Hub module Set Method Handler:WriteConsole.");

        // Register callback to be called when a message is received by the module
        await ioTHubModuleClient.SetInputMessageHandlerAsync("input1", PipeMessage, ioTHubModuleClient);
    }

    private static Task<MethodResponse> WriteConsole(MethodRequest methodRequest, object userContext)
    {
        return Task.Run( () => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Write direct method called!");
        return new MethodResponse(200);
                    });
    }
```

I get "Timed out waiting for device to connect" error when I stop my module by using the following command:

```
Stop-Service iotedge -NoWait
```

Error from portal:

[image]

But in your error message, there is "not registered" information. It seems your module not connected to the edge device or never running successfully.

So the first thing you need to do is checking the module log and to see if there is any error. Using the following command(replace your module name instead of "TestDirectMethodModule"):

```
docker logs TestDirectMethodModule -f
```

Check all the modules running status using the following command:

```
iotedge list
```

If all module running successfully you will see the following result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, i accidently called the direct method in the portal from the device level - could not work....

Comment: @FrankPfattheicher Glad to hear you found the problem. So do you call the direct method from the module level successfully?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In our case I think changing from MqttTransportSettings to AmqpTransportSettings solved the issue.

Comment: Calling direct method from device level doesn't work but module level.